# How to create a patch from root folder to a subfolder?

Tags: git

I need to synchronize sub-folder files with root-folder files. The problem is that the same files can have changes in both sides. I need to keep changes in sub-folder and add changes from the root one. I did very small change in the root folder to the important_file.txt changed the text `// changes made in b1` to `// changes made in b1 + mod1` (only `+ mod1`). I want to create a patch which will allow me to add this change to the file with the same name in sub-folder and keep other changes in it.

**Problem 1**

In order to do this I did an example repo [here](https://bitbucket.org/sarrag/merge_subfolders_test2/src/master/). I checkout B2 branch and executed the command:

```
git diff --no-index -- src/subfolder src/ > a.diff
```

After that I'm applying the patch with the command:

```
git apply a.diff
```

It doesn't apply the patch and returns an error

```
a.diff:71: trailing whitespace.
        return Ok(books);
error: src/subfolder/important_file.txt: already exists in working directory
```

**Problem 2**

I changed the direction when create the diff from `src/subfolder src/` to `src/ src/subfolder`. Now when I apply the patch it removes the file from the root folder.

Is there any other options to merge one folder to another in the way how branches are merged?

Comment: Your repo seems is not public, 'access denied'

Answer (score 1):

When you do `apply` you could specify different root and level. Please see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply documentation around `--directory` and `-p`.

Comment: It doesn't work. This option only prefixes the path, but this is not what I need.

Comment: @AlexanderGoida `-p` removes a prefix. I think you need `-p 2` in your scenario